# How to ignore digits that start with 0 (zero) using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match digits but I need to follow some rules.
The digits may (or may not) start with a sign [+-].
If the digits start with a 0 it can NOT be followed by anything.
But if it's 0 by itself, it should be matched.

I came up with the following regular expression:

```
[+-]*[1-9]\d*|[+-]*[0](?!\w)
```

But it's not working exactly as I need:

```
01 (matches 1, should match nothing)
9,000 (matches 9 and last 0, should match 9 only)
+0152 (matches 152, should match nothing)
-1200 (matches -1200, working as intended)
+0 (matches +0, working as intended)
```

[Live demostration](http://rubular.com/r/fMnOnxx5rp)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why not `[+-]?`?  Do we expect multiple plus and minus?

Comment: I'm learning regex, I used `*` meaning `0 or 1`, now I see it's `0 or many`. You're right, I should use `?`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[+-]?\b(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `[+-]?` - Match `+` or `-` optionally first
- `\b` - Assert a word boundary
- `(?:` - Start a non-capturing group

  - `0` - Match a single `0`
  - `|` - OR
  - `[1-9][0-9]*` - Match `1-9` followed by any digit 0 or more times
- `)` - End non-capturing group
- `\b` - Assert word boundary

Comment: This is perfect! I need to learn more about `\b` and `\(?:`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Regex:

```
^[+-]?[1-9]\d*|[+-]*[0](?!\w)$
```

- You don't need `*` after `[+-]` as it will match many signs, use `?` instead.
- And you will need to wrap your regex between `^`  and `$` so it matches the whole matching regex and giva wanted matches in your cases.

**Edit:**

You will need to use word boundary `\b` instead of `^`  and `$`, if you are dealing with words and not lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! `^` and `$` would not work for me because the digits may be between texts. I should have explained that, my bad.

Comment: So in that case you will need to use `\b` as suggested in the other answer.